# How to check in Heroku when the dyno had been restarted/ cycled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Would like to know what the log output should look like so I can search for it (note, I'm interested in when Heroku restarts the single web dyno or cycles generally or because of a runtime crash, NOT when I restart it because I've pushed a new version of the app or am setting new config variables). If this can also be found in New Relic, please advise how to do that as well.

For context, I want to know when this has been happening (I know it's automatic), because I suspect that my timer isn't working not because it's not working, but because everytime Heroku dyno is restarted, the timer resets to zero, thereby messing up any "daily" recurrence actions

Comment: what should the log output look like? i know the logs, but what am i looking for?

Comment: @james checkout https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Comment: I read it, couldn't find what I should be looking for in the logs, other than it saying that the logs should have it.